# Allocate dynamically and initialize multidimensional arrays without indexes

Tags: c

If I allocated a multidimensional array dynamically and **without using indexes** ( [ i ] [ j ] ), how can I initialize it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLUMNS 4

int main(void)
{
    int i,j;
    char **v;

    v = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char*));
    for (i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++)
        *(v + i * sizeof(char*)) = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++)
        for (j = 0 ; j < COLUMNS ; j++)
            ??? = 'a' + i * COLUMNS + j;
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of ??? what do I have to put? Addresses aren't contiguous so I think this expression:

```
**(v+(i*COLUMNS+j)*sizeof(char))
```

isn't correct...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not multiply by the size of the type, pointer arithmetics is done in multiples of the base type.
2. You need to dereference like you do above, and then dereference again, like this

   ```
   int i, j;
   char **v;

   v = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char *));
   if (v == NULL)
       return -1;
   for (i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++)
   {
       *(v + i) = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(char));
       if (*(v + i) == NULL)
           return -1;
       for (j = 0 ; j < COLUMNS ; j++)
       {
           *(*(v + i) + j) = 'a' + i * COLUMNS + j;
       }
   }

   return 0;
   ```

   and don't forget to `free()`.

So basically `x[i]` is equivalent to `*(x + i)` and you can apply it to the resulting pointer too.

**NOTE**: These are not *strings*, they need to be `nul` terminated to become *strings*.

If you insist on using `sizeof` this is how

```
    int i, j;
    char **v;

    v = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char *));
    if (v == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++)
    {
        *((unsigned char *) v + i * sizeof(char *)) = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(char));
        if (*(v + i) == NULL)
            return -1;
        for (j = 0 ; j < COLUMNS ; j++)
        {
            *(*((unsigned char *) v + i * sizeof(char *)) + j) = 'a' + i * COLUMNS + j;
        }
    }
```

I will not use `sizeof(char)` as it's very redundant, the standard clearly states that `sizeof(char)` **MUST** be 1.

Comment: Then, isn't there the problem of space not used (by array _v_) between a row and another one?

Comment: What? I don't understand your question! can you explain why that worries you?

Comment: If I print `*(v+i)+j` I obtain **0x...18**, 0x...19, 0x...20, 0x...21, **0x...28**, ..., **0x...38**, ... first addresses of each row, there are 16 bytes after the previous one's.

Comment: Because each pointer uses 4bytes on your system, that's not wasted space, it's just how an array of pointers is stored.

Comment: @Rabbid76 indeed I found (can I say find?) a core dump with your program.

Comment: And is there no way to do that using **sizeof**?

Comment: You DONT NEED `sizeof`. Why would you want to use it?

Comment: If it's possibile I'd like to see how to do that with sizeof... Why not?

Comment: If you try compile your last code it does a warning and an error.

Comment: @SimoneBonato are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I post the errors: warning assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast and invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Comment: I tried removing (unsigned char *) cast and compiler doesn't give errors, but main returns -1...

Answer (score 1):

You are not creating a multi-dimensional array but an array of pointers. In your code, a possibility is to put `*((*(v + i)) + j)` in place of your `???`.

Otherwise if you want the addresses to be contiguous like a multi-dimensional array you need to allocate all the memory in one `malloc`, assign it to `v`, and then use `*(v + i*COLUMNS + j)` to access it.

Comment: In this case I can also access using indexes: `v[i * COLUMNS + j]`, correct?

Comment: Yeah in the second case your expression is OK; the question asked how to do it without indices.